# Why the name in listView keep changing?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a `listView` in Activity A as shown below. All the values and name were actually returned from Activity C to B then only A.

[image]

When the first list is clicked, it should display text `Project` and value `3` on `editText` B. But it displays `Medical` which was actually getting from the last list.

[image]

After I change the value from 3 to 43 and return to A, the name changed. What should I do so that the name will remain the same ?

[image]

**Activity A**

```
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
      ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
      int mClickedPosition;
      adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String (getActivity(),R.layout.claims,R.id.textView1,m_listItems);
     listV = (ListView) claims.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

               listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  // if list clicked
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position;


                if (name.equals("Project")) {
                    String temp[] = m_listItems.get(position).split("\\s\\s+");
                    result = temp[temp.length - 1].trim();
                    result = result.replace("RM","");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), Project1.class);
                    intent.putExtra("bitmap", true); // image
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("result", result);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                    Log.e("RESULT", "Result= " + result);
                }
                else if(name.equals("Medical"))
                {
                    String temp[] = m_listItems.get(position).split("\\s\\s+");
                    result = temp[temp.length - 1].trim();
                    result = result.replace("RM","");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), Medical.class);
                    intent.putExtra("bitmap", true);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("result", result);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            }
        });
        return claims;
       }


   @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:  // for Project
                result = data.getStringExtra("text"); //get from B
                name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                description = data.getStringExtra("c");
                as = Long.parseLong(result);
                Log.d("FIRST", "result:" + result);
                Text = "  " + name + "                                  " + "RM" + result + "";
                if (mClickedPosition == -1) { // if is icon button clicked
                    m_listItems.add(Text);

                } else {
                    m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition, Text);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                break;

            case 1:  // for Medical
                result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                description = data.getStringExtra("c");
                as = Long.parseLong(result);
                Log.d("FIRST", "result:" + result);
                Text = "  " + name + "                                  " + "RM" + result + "";
                // m_listItems.clear();
                if (mClickedPosition==-1)
                {
                    m_listItems.add(Text);

                }
                else
                {
                    m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition, Text);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                break;
```

**Activity B** (Project1)

```
   if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { //if  has value pass from A
            final String Amount = getIntent().getExtras().getString("result");
            final String description1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");
            txt1.setText(description1);
            txt.setText(Amount);
        }

                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // return to A
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                        a = "Project";
                        text = txt.getText().toString(); // amount
                        returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("c", c); // receive from Activity C
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                       finish();
                    }
                });
                       viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img); // receive from C
                  }
```

**Noted that the `result` in Activity A represents value 3,5 while `name` represents `project` and `Medical`**. How can I fix this ? Please help.

Comment: From where does variable `name` in Activity A get its value?

Comment: @FabinPaul get from `a` in Activity B

Comment: @FabinPaul The code for `Project1` and `Medical` is the same, just the `a` is different

Comment: what is temp used for in Activity A?

Comment: @FabinPaul I just want to get `result` (3 or 5) display on B editText. If I not using   `String temp[] = m_listItems.get(position).split("\\s\\s+");`, I will get `name + " " + result ` display on editText B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, your variable `name` in Activity A contains previously resulted value (from Activity B) and not from row you have clicked on listview i.e. "Medical" value you previously got from Activity B which held by variable `name` and on your listview click event you have checks the if `name` is "Medical" or "Project" (and in this case it is "Medical" and hence Medical activity is started).

One solution is to get the value("Project/Medical") from listview.

Try this code.
Activity A

```
  mClickedPosition = position;
  String temp[] = m_listItems.get(position).split("\\s\\s+");
  result = temp[temp.length - 1].trim();
  result = result.replace("RM","");
  name = temp[1].trim();
  if (name.equals("Project")) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), Project1.class);
                intent.putExtra("bitmap", true);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("result", result);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                Log.e("RESULT", "Result= " + result);
            }
            else if(name.equals("Medical"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), Medical.class);
                intent.putExtra("bitmap", true);
                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                intent.putExtra("result", result);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
```

Comment: Glad I could help..:)

Comment: Bro can I ask one more question? I have passed  image (Global.img) from  C to B, then A.  However, I don't want the image display on `listView` A. When the list is clicked and `intent` to B,  `intent.putExtra("bitmap", true);`, the image only displays (which is under the editText) on `imageview` B.

Comment: Do I need to use custom listView ? Or can use this method?

Comment: So you want to display the image in Activity B?

Comment: @Tony I don't think you should pass bitmaps via intent. Better way will be to send file path of the image.

Comment: So Global.img is a bitmap?

Comment: Ok.. For simple applications this will suffice, but for larger applications where memory is a concern, you shouldn't follow this pattern because holding static bitmap across activities can cause memory out of bound exception. Like @surfian told get the path of the image and pass this string path as intent argument and decode bitmap from this path and display the bitmap

Comment: Sorry @Sufian my bad...SO won't let you edit previous comments :(

Comment: @Tony and Fabin avoid using static fields or even singletons. They create uncertainty because you never know their life span/cycle. To share data across activities, always use **parcelable**, **serializable**, or other supported types. Passing bitmaps will be heavy and could crash your app like Fabin said.

Comment: @FabinPaul no problem. :) Just avoid using static fields for the above reason.

Comment: Any hints ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193767/how-do-i-scale-down-a-bitmap-without-effect-the-quality